The specified language version is too high issue in Flutter
I just bought a new Mac Laptop and trying to run a old project from 2022. I think I have already updated Xcode, Dart, Flutter, packages and Coacopod to the latest version in my new Macbook.
I'm just wondering why I'm getting this error. I have already tried deleting the pod file, did flutter clean..etc but it's still not working for some reason so any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.
Error
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           11.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-3.0.0/lib/modal_bottom_sheet.dart:1:1: Error: The specified language version is too high. The highest supported language version is 3.2.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

pubspec.yaml file
dependencies:
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre

My Flutter and Dart Version
Dart SDK version: 3.2.3 (stable) (Tue Dec 5 17:58:33 2023 +0000) on "macos_arm64"


Flutter 3.16.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b0366e0a3f (5 months ago) • 2023-12-05 19:46:39 -0800
Engine • revision 54a7145303
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet/versions

modal_bottom_sheet seems to require dart sdk of at least 3.3.0. You can either try doing flutter upgrade and setting the sdk in your pubspec to sdk: ">=3.3.0 <4.0.0", or downgrading to a lower version of modal_bottom_sheet.
